# Передать все элементы массива в метод класса

Tags: php, ооп

Есть такой класс, который после конвертации импортирует данные в другой класс методом `execute()`, и конвертеров может быть несколько (массив `$converters`). У меня получается передать только один конвертер в метод, по его ключу. А как передать все ?

```html
class Import
{
    private $reader;
    private $writer;
    private $converters = [];

    public function from(Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
        return $this;
    }

    public function to(Writer $writer)
    {
        $this->writer = $writer;
        return $this;
    }

    public function with(Converter $converter)
    {
        $this->converters[] = $converter;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function execute()
    {
        
        $toWrite = $this->converters[0]->convert($this->reader->read());
        $this->writer->write($toWrite);
    }
}

$importer = new Import();

$importer->from(new ArrayReader());
$importer->to(new FileWriter());
$importer->with(new UpperCaseConverter());
$importer->with(new LowerCaseConverter());
$importer->execute();
```

Comment: Можете реализовать через [Chain of responsibility](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility/php/example) шаблон, либо самостоятельно, делая конверсию по конвертерам в массиве, а затем результат передавая на запись.

Comment: Может вот это поможет https://www.php.net/func_get_args ? Есть средство для передачи в функцию произвольного количества аргументов, если изначально аргументы не декларировались.

Comment: что вам без заумных слов мешает  написать банальный цикл, который проходится по всем конвертерам, а не только по первому?

Comment: Спасибо! Точно, нужен был простой цикл))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если несколько, то замените один вызов на цикл

```
public function execute(){
    $result = $this->reader->read();
    foreach($this->converters as $c){
        $result = $c->convert($result);
    }
    $this->writer->write($result);
}
```